Не получается установить symfony на ПК через docker
Есть ПК с windows 11, на нём установлен docker.
Поднял контейнеры с nginx, php-cli, php-fpm, mariadb.
Пытаюсь установить symfony командой
docker-compose run --rm php-cli curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash

Получаю
Symfony CLI installer

Environment check
  [*] cURL is installed
  [*] Tar is installed
  [*] Git is installed
  [*] Your architecture (amd64) is supported

Download
  Downloading https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/releases/latest/download/symfony-cli_linux_amd64.tar.gz...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 5544k  100 5544k    0     0  2401k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 4502k
  Uncompress binary...
  Installing the binary into your home directory...
  The binary was saved to: /home/a/.symfony5/bin/symfony

The Symfony CLI was installed successfully!

Use it as a local file:
  export PATH="$HOME/.symfony5/bin:$PATH"

Or install it globally on your [system][1]:
  mv /home/a/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

Then start a new shell and run 'symfony'

Теперь чтобы установить symfony, как сказано в выводе команды "globally on your system" запускаю:
docker-compose run --rm php-cli mv /home/a/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

но получаю ошибку:
mv: cannot stat '/home/a/.symfony5/bin/symfony': No such file or directory

Т.е. в контейнере такая папка не создалась??
И ещё, вчера после обновления докера начал получать ошибки типа:
<3>WSL (31168) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:577: execvpe /bin/bash failed 2

в результате пришлось ставить
wsl --install Ubuntu
wsl -s Ubuntu

и перезагружаться. (И ещё попробовал kali-linux поставить) Ещё в процессе установки Ubuntu заставили пользователя создать и пароль к нему.
Так вот  mv /home/a/.symfony5/bin/symfony - пользователь a - это и есть тот самый пользователь, которого я создал при установке Ubuntu.
Получается, что бинарник symfony он установил куда-то внутрь Ubuntu.
А команда
docker-compose run --rm php-cli mv /home/a/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

обращается внутрь контейнера php-cli который работает на alpine.
Получается кроме контейнера php-cli, работающего на alpine мне пришлось зачем-то ставить ещё Ubuntu, поднимать там пользователя с паролем. И теперь бинарники скачиваются внутрь Ubuntu, а не
внутрь моего контейнера php-cli. Это как вообще? Кто-то может объяснить?

Ты как-то не по идеологии докера хочешь поставить Симфони. 1. Чем не устроил рекомендуемый образ? 2. Зачем --rm, если ты планируешь продолжать пользоваться контейнером?
